# api google map, no puedo acceder a map desde fuera de la función

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

tengo la api funcionando (html y js) cuando carga la web inicializa el mapa por lo que funciona, pongo marcadores y tal. pero necesito que al darle a un boton en html me ponga en unas coordenadas concretas un bocadillo de infoWindow con un texto.
El problema es que desde dentro del initMap() (el que inicializa cuando carga la web y muestra el mapa y marcadores) desde ahí si puedo llamar a otras funciones y tal, pero si lo hago desde el boton de fuera, no me guarda la variable map
var map; está inicializada al principio del script luego initMap() y en el html tengo el onclick con la función:

```
// Función para mostrar un InfoWindow en coordenadas específicas
function mostrarInfoWindow() {
if (!map) {
console.error('El mapa no ha sido inicializado correctamente.');
return;
}

const lat = -34.397; // Latitud de las coordenadas específicas
const lng = 150.644; // Longitud de las coordenadas específicas

const contentString = '<div><h1>InfoWindow</h1><p>Contenido del InfoWindow</p></div>';

const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString,
position: { lat, lng },
map: map
});

infowindow.open(map);
}
```

pero me da error en que "map" no está undefined, pero en initmap() se inicializó

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), configuracionmapa);
```

y la variable map está fuera del initmap...

la función initmap:

```js
var infoWindow
var map =null;
function initMap() {

  // The map, centered at Uluru
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), configuracionmapa);
  // console.log(configuracionmapa.center.lat)
  //ajusto la posicion del icono un poco mas baja
  var latbaja=uluru.lat-0.00015;
  uluruicono={lat:latbaja,lng:uluru.lng};

   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        // position: uluruicono,
        // icon: image,
        map: map,
        title: "Latitude:"+uluru.lat+" | Longitude:"+uluru.lng
    });

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      // gr= { lat: 40.365039, lng: -3.646361 };
      infoWindow.setPosition(uluru);
      infoWindow.setContent("posición: "+uluru.lat+", "+uluru.lng+" precisión: "+ precision);
      // console.log("posición: "+uluru.lat+", "+uluru.lng+" precisión: "+ precision)
      // infoWindow.open(map);

      map.setCenter(uluru);

      // openMap(maxlat,maxlon,minlat,minlon);

      map.addListener('idle', function() {
            bounds = map.getBounds();
            southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
            northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
            newmaxlat = northEast.lat();
            newmaxlon = northEast.lng();
            newminlat = southWest.lat();
            newminlon = southWest.lng();
            zoom_actual = map.getZoom();

            //funcion para obtener un objeto con las coordenadas y zoom
            obtenerdatoswifi(newmaxlat,newmaxlon,newminlat,newminlon,zoom_actual);

            // obtenercoordenadas(northEast.lat(),southWest.lat(),northEast.lng(),southWest.lng(),map.getZoom());

        medialat=(newmaxlat+newminlat)/2;
        medialon=(newmaxlon+newminlon)/2;
            // obtenercoordenadasphp(medialat,medialon,zoom_actual);
        console.log({medialat,medialon,zoom_actual})
            sessionStorage.setItem('centrolat', medialat);
            sessionStorage.setItem('centrolon', medialon);
            sessionStorage.setItem('centrozoom', zoom_actual);

            sessionStorage.setItem('maxlat', newmaxlat);
            sessionStorage.setItem('minlat', newminlat);
            sessionStorage.setItem('maxlon', newmaxlon);
            sessionStorage.setItem('minlon', newminlon);
            var mapa=map;
            console.log({mapa})
            sessionStorage.setItem('elmapa', mapa);


        });//fin actualizacion mapa


      //guardo el map en un sesion storage
      // sessionStorage.setItem("map", map);
      // console.log({map})
      // var resstoragemap=sessionStorage.getItem("map")
      // console.log({resstoragemap})
console.log(map)
}//fin funcion


window.initMap = initMap;
```

el resto de funciones a las que llama no son relevantes, solo son llamadas a funciones posteriores o a variables de configuración.

Comment: Por favor agrega todo el código relevante... donde esta la funcion de la que hablas que se llama `initMap()`? tienes otra llamada `configuracionmapa`? esa donde está? que hace? Agrega todo el código completo relativo al problema

Answer (score -1, accepted):

al final se ha solucionado copiando las variables declaradas fuera de las funciones, y puestas como globales en el primer script que carga el DOM.